# how to add an asterix for the LabelFor helper?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am building an MVC 4 app.  I have a field called OrganisationId, which is mandatory.

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.OrganisationId)
```

I need to put an asterix after the label is the field is required.
How do I access the LabelFor templates? where are they stored?  How do I create my own?

Thanks

Comment: you need to do this thing on the model class..

Comment: Rahual - can you please explain a bit more or give me some samples?

Answer (score 0):

On your model use data annotations

```
  [Required]
  [UIHint("RequiredTemplate")]//this does the trick which should match the file name.
  [Display(Name="Organization Id")]
  public string Name { get; set; }
```

Drop a new folder in Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates
Create a new PARTIAL VIEW RequiredTemplate.cshtml.

```
<font style="color:Red">*</font>@Html.LabelFor(m => m)
```

In your view where organization should be use DisplayFor

```
  <div class="display-field">
     @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Name)
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a HTML Extension:

```
public static MvcHtmlString LabelForX<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, string requiredText = "required", string innerText = "*" )
{
    ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);
    string htmlFieldName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
    string labelText = metadata.DisplayName ?? metadata.PropertyName ?? htmlFieldName.Split('.').Last();
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(labelText))
    {
        return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
    }

    var tag = new TagBuilder("label");
    tag.Attributes.Add("for", html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(htmlFieldName));
    tag.SetInnerText(labelText);

    if (metadata.IsRequired)
    {
        var span = new TagBuilder("abbr");
        span.Attributes.Add("title", requiredText);
        span.Attributes.Add("class", "labelRequired");
        span.SetInnerText(innerText);
        tag.Attributes.Add("class", "labelRequired");
        tag.InnerHtml = span.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal) + "&nbsp;" + labelText;
    }
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal)); 
}
```

Then it is used like this:

```
@Html.LabelForX(x => x.YourRequieredField)
```

I changed all my `LabelFor` for my new `LabelForX`... so, if my Model/ViewModel property has a [Required] it will display a "*" using a `<abbr>` tag.

I created a CSS class "labelRequired" that is applied to the label and the "*", so you can style the requiered labels different from the normal ones.